# Sonar Collecting data from multiple sonar instances

Tags: sonarqube

I would like to know if there is capability in Sonar to collect Code Metrics data from other sonar.

The thing I would like to achieve is that say suppose there are 10 sonars running on 10 different machine.

And I have a sonar running on my machine which would pull the data from all the other 10 sonars and display the same. So, that I don’t need to check each individual sonar.

Appreciate any information or help on the same.

Answer (score 1):

What about using the webservice api interface?

http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Web+Service+API

http:// server-address:9000 / ...

... /api/resources - all projects
... /api/metrics - all metrics

...

so it does not seem too difficult

for fetching in java see http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Using+the+Web+Service+Java+client

Answer (score 1):

Hello
You should rather ask this question on sonar user mailing list: http://www.sonarsource.org/support/support/

Maybe I did not understood correctly your question but I think you can solve your problem by using a single sonar instance, running build & analysis processes on 10 different machines.
In my company, like in many others, we are using hudson/jenkins to schedule sonar analysis on many different machines. Each hudson node will inject quality measures on the same single sonar database. This is done easily using sonar hudson/jenkins plugin.
Hope it helps